# Find MongoDB documents by subdocument size

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "some_key" : "some_value",
    ...,
    "another_key" : {
        "a key" : "a value",
        ...
    }
}
```

There are a couple different types of documents that go into this collection, with the biggest differences happening in the "another_key" field.

I would like to be able to find documents based on the size of the subdocument in "another_key". If it were an array, I could use this query:

```
{
    "another_key" : {
        $size : 0
    }
}
```

to find all documents for which it has been left empty. Unfortunately, as per [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/#op._S_size) this only works for arrays.

Is there a way to do this for subdocuments?

Comment: Nested objects aren't really subdocuments, and thus shouldn't be referred to as subdocuments, since they don't act like a document, and can't use $ operators on them. I would suggest turn another_key into an array of objects(subdocuments) that looks like: {key: 'akey, value: 'avalue'}. you can now find the $size, and key if you want. db.collection.find({'another_key.key': 'aKey}) etc.

Comment: Can you explain more about the use case for this? It's pretty weird to want to do something like this, honestly, and I'd like to know what the overall goal is. Perhaps there's a better approach? Using `$where` is generally a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @wdberkeley My particular use case is that I'm using data that someone else is providing, and I want to write a script that verifies that the data won't get messed up when their code is updated. In my case I can just check for it being empty, but I was wondering about the more general problem.

Comment: @BrianNoah You should write that up as a full answer. It won't work in my case because I'm not the one creating the data, but it could help others.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the sub-documents keys and the [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where) operator.

```js
db.collection.find( { 
    'timestamp': "your value",
    '$where': function() { return Object.keys(this.another_key).length === 0; } 
})
```

Comment: $where is not very performant, and will be incredibly slow on large collections.

Answer (score 1):

Nested objects aren't really subdocuments, and I don't refer to them as subdocuments, since they don't act like a document, and can't use `$` operators on them. Also indexing doesn't really work on them, however we can index 'another_key.key' for better search performance.

I would suggest turn `another_key` into an array of objects(subdocuments) that looks like:

```
db.items.insert({
    some_key : 'some_value',
    another_key : [
        {key: 'akey', value: 'avalue'},
        {key: 'bkey', value: 'bvalue'}
    ]
});
```

You can now find by $size, and key if you want.

```
mongos> db.items.find({another_key: {$size: 0}})
 // 0 documents
mongos> db.items.find({another_key: {$size: 1}})
 // 0 documents
mongos> db.items.find({another_key: {$size: 2}})
 { "_id" : ObjectId("54f62a48e2fdcc95d4934424"), "some_key" : "some_value", "another_key" : [ { "key" : "akey", "value" : "avalue" }, { "key" : "bkey", "value" : "bvalue" } ] }
mongos> db.items.find({another_key: {$size: 3}})
 // 0 documents

mongos> db.collection.find({'another_key.key': 'akey'})
 { "_id" : ObjectId("54f62a48e2fdcc95d4934424"), "some_key" : "some_value", "another_key" : [ { "key" : "akey", "value" : "avalue" }, { "key" : "bkey", "value" : "bvalue" } ] }
```

Unfortunately you can't do comparitive `$size` queries:

```
mongos> db.items.find({another_key: {$size: {$gt:1} } } )
 error: {
     "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $size needs a number",
     "code" : 17287
 }
```